Is it possible to submit private bundled transactions on chains other than ethereum mainnet?
my ethereum wallet was hacked via chrome extension and my private key was leaked.
After stealing all my main assets, he left me about 20% of my networth in the account and has setup a sniper bots on eth mainnet and few other L2s..
So I started my conquest to recover my Defi locked assets.
I found this library called flashbots which let you send bundle transactions directly to miners and execute them before the bots can see it on public mempool.
While i was successfully able to do it on eth mainnet somehow i couldnt manage to do it on other chains as flashbots do not support anything other than mainnet.
Is there any way to do the same for chains like 'arbitrum', scroll and other L2s?
Heres my code snippet:
    const { JsonRpcProvider, Wallet, ethers } = require("ethers"); //import https://docs.ethers.org/
    const { FlashbotsBundleProvider, FlashbotsBundleResolution } = require("@flashbots/ethers-provider-bundle") //import https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flashbots/ethers-provider-bundle
    const { exit } = require('process');
    require('dotenv').config();

    const bundles = require("./resources/bundles")
    const services = require("./resources/services")
    const utils = require("./resources/utils")

    // sepolia
    // const FLASHBOTS_ENDPOINT = 'https://relay-sepolia.flashbots.net'//change for mainnet
    // const CHAIN_ID = 11155111;
    // const recipientAddress = ""; // Address where you want to send ERC20 tokens
    // const tokenAddress = ""; // Address of the ERC20 token contract
    // const amount = ethers.parseUnits("1000", 18); //change accordingly

    // mainnet
    const FLASHBOTS_ENDPOINT = "https://relay.flashbots.net";
    const CHAIN_ID = 1;
    const INFURA_PROJECT_ID = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<Infura API Key>";

    // a normal ethers.js provider, to perform gas estimiations and nonce lookups
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(INFURA_PROJECT_ID);

    // `authSigner` is an Ethereum private key that does NOT store funds and is NOT your bot's primary key.
    // This is an identifying key for signing payloads to establish reputation and whitelisting, only for signing request payloads, not transactions
    // In production, this should be used across multiple bundles to build relationship. In this example, we generate a new wallet each time
    const authSigner = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();

    // Account sponsoring the gas fee
    // const sponsor = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.SPONSOR_PHRASE).connect(provider);
    const sponsor = ethers.Wallet.fromPhrase(process.env.SPONSOR_PHRASE).connect(provider);

    // compromised account
    const compromised = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.COMPROMISED_KEY).connect(provider);

    const safeAddress = sponsor.address;
    console.log("Safe Wallet: ", safeAddress);
    const compromisedAddress = compromised.address;
    console.log("Compromised Wallet: ", compromisedAddress);

    // Create a contract instance for the ERC20 token (Dai)
    // ABI definition for the transfer function of ERC20 token
    // const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, [
    //     "function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"
    // ], compromised);

    // Encode the function data for the transfer function
    // const transactionData = tokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData(
    //     "transfer", 
    //     [recipientAddress, amount]
    // );

    const simulate = async (transactionBundle) => {
        console.log("[Simulation] Entering Dark Forest...");
        const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, authSigner, FLASHBOTS_ENDPOINT, 'mainnet')

        provider.on("block", async (blockNumber) => {
            console.log(`Current Block: ${blockNumber}`);
            const targetBlockNumber = blockNumber + 1;
            console.log(`Preparing bundle for next block: ${targetBlockNumber}`);
            const signedBundle = await flashbotsProvider.signBundle(transactionBundle);
            //run simulation
            let simulation = await services.simulate(flashbotsProvider, targetBlockNumber, signedBundle)
            console.log("Sending bundle.");
            console.log(utils.safeJsonStringify(simulation))
            exit(0);
        })
    }

    const execute = async (transactionBundle) => {
        console.log("[Real Tx] Entering Dark Forest...");
        const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, authSigner, FLASHBOTS_ENDPOINT, 'mainnet')

        provider.on("block", async (blockNumber) => {
            console.log(`Current Block: ${blockNumber}`);
            const targetBlockNumber = blockNumber + 1;
            console.log(`Preparing bundle for next block: ${targetBlockNumber}`);
            const signedBundle = await flashbotsProvider.signBundle(transactionBundle);
            //run simulation
            await services.simulate(flashbotsProvider, targetBlockNumber, signedBundle)
            console.log("Sending bundle.");
            // send bundle
            if(process.env.DO_TRANSACTION == 1) {
                console.log("performing real transaction")
                await services.sendBundle(flashbotsProvider, targetBlockNumber, signedBundle)
            }
            else {
                console.log("real transaction is disabled")
                exit(1)
            }
        })

    }

    const main = async () => {
        const method = process.env.METHOD;
        let safeNonce = await utils.getAccurateNonce(provider, safeAddress);
        let compromisedNonce = await utils.getAccurateNonce(provider, compromisedAddress);
        const transactionBundle = bundles.fetchAllTokens_Type2(sponsor, compromised)

        switch (method) {
            case 'simulate':
                simulate(transactionBundle);
                break;
            case 'execute':
                execute(transactionBundle);
                break;
            default:
                console.log('No valid method specified');
        }
    }

    main()

